# Angular Spectator: Changing mocked Service Properties

Tags: angular, angular-test

I'm using spectator and jest for angular testing. I would like to change the properties of a mocked service in the following setup:

```
describe('SearchComponent', () => {
  let spectator: Spectator<SearchComponent>;

  const createComponent = createComponentFactory({
    component: SearchComponent,
    providers: [
      mockProvider(SearchService, {
        isActive$: of(false),  // to be changed
      }),
    ],
    shallow: true,
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    spectator = createComponent();
  });

  it('should display bar if isActive(true)', () => {

  });

  it('should display foo if isActive(false)', () => {

  });

});
```

How could I change the value of isActive$?

Answer (score 1):

Should work with a factory and temporary saved provider mock... Something like this worked for me (**did not test this version, sorry**):

```js
class SearchServiceMock implements Partial<SearchService> {
    public isActive = of(false);
}

describe('SearchComponent', () => {
    let spectator: Spectator<SearchComponent>;
    let searchServiceMock: SearchServiceMock;

    const createComponent = createComponentFactory({
        component: SearchComponent,
        shallow: true,

        spectator = createComponent(
            providers: [
            {
                provide: SearchService,
                useFactory: () => {
                    searchServiceMock = new SearchServiceMock();
                    return searchServiceMock;
                }
      ],
        );
    });

    beforeEach(() => {
        spectator = createComponent();
    });

    it('should display bar if isActive(true)', () => {
        searchServiceMock.isAcrive = of(true);

        spectator = createComponent();

        // ... test here ...

    });

    it('should display foo if isActive(false)', () => {

    });

});
```

Sorry for the short answer, not sure whether anybody is interested anyway. And it feels really dirty.